# How to style the wp_list_page in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to style the list the wp_list_page outputs, basically i would like to wrap every single page in a rounded box. All that I seem to be able to do is style the LI and UL on the CSS but i doesn't work.

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out puts the follwing kind of html.

Make sure to wrap it with `ul` like this `<ul class="main-nav"><?php wp_list_pages(); ?></ul>`

This is the typical output.

```
 <li class="pagenav">Pages
   <ul>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="/">Sample Page</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

In your css you can edit it like so.

```
li.page_item {border:1px solid green;}
li.page_item a {color:yellow;}
etc...
```

If you want the page links to be rounded you can insert the border-radius syntax.

```
li.page_item {border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
```

}

Comment: Thanks andrewk. But it doesn't work for some reason. Here is the link of the page

http://www.museidibra.it/prova/turismo-a-bra/

upper right side.

Thanks again

Comment: The pages seem rounded in chrome and Firefox, are you using IE?